# Understanding this 16-bit PRNG

Tags: c, 16-bit, prng, unsigned-integer

I found [this algorithm](http://b2d-f9r.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/16-bit-xorshift-rng-now-with-more.html) for a 16-bit PRNG. I don't understand what x, y and t are. What I want to do is use a 16-bit seed to generate multiple random 16-bit values.

If I'm correct, the function shown in that webpage (quoted below) is only pseudo code, since as it stands, it will always generate the same value, since x and y are local variables to the function?

```
uint16_t rnd_xorshift_32() {
  static uint16_t x=1,y=1;
  uint16_t t=(x^(x<<5)); 
  x=y; 
  return y=(y^(y>>1))^(t^(t>>3));
}
```

How could the above be modified to read a global variable `uint_16_t random` (which will have been pre-set with a seed), and then overwrite it with the next random value?

**Edit**: Thanks, so my understanding of the static variables has been corrected. Would I be correct in saying that `x` and `y` are initially set to the seed (both to `1` in the above code) and are then modified to become the subsequent random values? And `t` is a temporary variable?

Comment: They are static. Values are kept between calls. Static declaration also used only once so it starts with 1, not executed anymore and kept in memory for next call.

Comment: They are local variables, but they don't have automatic storage duration - `static` means that `x` and `y` always refer to the same instance of the variables, they persist between function calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "static" mean in a C program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572547/what-does-static-mean-in-a-c-program)

Answer (score 3):

The variables `x` and `y` are not truly "local" to the function in the sense that you imply.  They are declared as `static` which means while their *scope* is local to the function (they cannot be accessed by name from outside), their *lifetime* is that of the entire program.  So they will retain their values between calls, which means two things:

- x and y are in fact the PRNG state.
- The function is not thread-safe.

Comment: C99 6.2.4:3 on a static variable: “Its lifetime is the entire execution”. Your alternative formulation “from (no later than) the function's first invocation until (no earlier than) the last” is not shorter, not simpler, and not equivalent to the official one when the address of the variable is passed around and accessed after the last invocation of the function it is local to.

Comment: Thank you for the citation.  Not having the standard in front of me, I was being deliberately conservative, but your point is well taken.  Do you know if it was the same prior to C99?

Comment: The corresponding sentence in C89 is “The object exists and retains
its last-stored value throughout the execution of the entire
program.”